# How to create stored procedures on sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I started to learn sequelize with nodejs and I already maked a simple crud and start a new table on my database, but I do not have no clue about stored procedures with sequelize.
I did not find anything on the documentation...
It is possible to creat stored procedures with sequelize?
if so, how?

PS: I am using mysql 5.7.23

Comment: What sort of "procedures"? Do you mean "stored procedures"?

Comment: @tadman yes, stored procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create them and use them using regular queries. There's no specific wrapper for them since Sequelize is an abstraction layer around different databases, each of which has its own method for defining and executing stored procedures.

In Sequelize it's pretty easy to run [raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) and define these:

```
sequelize.query("DEFINE ...");
```

Comment: I understand, but in my case i am using a shared database for 2 application: 1 in nodejs and 1 in java. So for nodejs this will work fine but for my java application will not get acces in this procedures.

Sorry for any mistake, english is not my mother language.

Comment: Why wouldn't Java have access to stored procedures defined by Node.js? MySQL doesn't really care how you define them. If they're successfully created they'll be available for use.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I thought you have said to just make a query to do the same thing my procedure does and not create the procedure with the query. Thanks a lot @tadman.